# Delphi: Automatic scaling of GridPanel in frame

Tags: delphi, layout, scaling, vcl, delphi-10.1-berlin

I've got a single row GridPanel full of buttons in a frame which I wan't to scale proportionally when either the height or width gets changed.

[image: Here's the layout of the frame in a form]

Before posting I set the alignment to alClient to use the parent's full size, but I don't know what to do about scaling.

What would you suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within the `GridPanel` you have a `ColumCollection` with four (acc. your image) `TColumnItems`.

For each `TColumnItem`, set the `SizeStyle` property to `ssPercent` (the default) and the `Value` property to 25.

Because the other columns sizes are adjusted automatically when you edit one column, it is easier to edit these values when changing the form (or frame in your case) view to text. Right-click on the frame and select `View as Text`.

It looks as follows when edited.

```
  object GridPanel1: TGridPanel
    Left = 0
    Top = 0
    Width = 426
    Height = 108
    Align = alClient
    Caption = 'GridPanel1'
    ColumnCollection = <
      item
        Value = 25.000000000000000000
      end
      item
        Value = 25.000000000000000000
      end
      item
        Value = 25.000000000000000000
      end
      item
        Value = 25.000000000000000000
      end>
    ControlCollection = <
    ...
    >
    RowCollection = <
      item
        Value = 100.000000000000000000
      end>
    TabOrder = 0
    object Button1: TButton
      Left = 1
      Top = 1
      Width = 106
      Height = 106
      Align = alClient
      Caption = 'Button1'
      TabOrder = 0
      ExplicitLeft = 40
      ExplicitTop = 32
      ExplicitWidth = 75
      ExplicitHeight = 25
    end
    ...other buttons
    ExplicitWidth = 320
    ExplicitHeight = 153
  end
```

Your response:

> That is something I forgot to mention I had already done. To clarify, my issue has to do with forcing a certain ratio (in my case 1:1) of height to width while resizing the frame (or possibly the surrounding form).

I assume the ratio 1:1 applies to each button, so 4:1 for the whole frame.

Because the user may resize either the height or the width (or both) of the form, and we only have the common `OnResize` event to lean on, I suggest the following:

Declare two private variables in the form

```
    OldCW, OldCH: integer; // for client width and client height respectively
```

and the `OnResize` event of the form:

```
procedure TForm4.FormResize(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if ClientWidth <> OldCW then
    ClientHeight := ClientWidth div 4
  else
    ClientWidth := ClientHeight * 4;
  OldCW := ClientWidth;
  OldCH := ClientHeight;
end;
```

Finally, for future questions of yours: Please explain what you have already tried to solve the problem, and why those attempts failed.

Comment: That is something I forgot to mention I had already done. To clarify, my issue has to do with forcing a certain ratio (in my case 1:1) of height to width while resizing the frame (or possibly the surrounding form).